# Is it possible to view the data received from a JPEG RTSP stream in VLC Media Player?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, streaming, jpeg

I'm streaming JPEGs to VLC via Live555, but there are a few issues with how they are displayed, I want to be able to view the data of a frame in order to compare it with the original image and determine what the cause of the issue is. Is this possible?
Does the snapshot functionality change the way the image is encoded/compressed, or does it actually just save the frame as an image? (provided that the output is the same filetype as the input).